# How to return value from database into a variable

Tags: c#, sql

```
static float ExecuteQueryWithResult_fl(SqlConnection connection, string query)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                float prev_val = ((float)command.ExecuteScalar());
                return prev_val;
            }
        }
```

Call :

```
float f = ExecuteQueryWithResult_fl(connection, prev_status);
```

Iam using this in a client application that communicates with server , whenever this line is about to be executed : The connection breaks ! No error comes out . What may be the problem ??

```
public static void update_data_base(string type_id,int station, int ioa, byte by_val, float fl, uint bcr, bool is_float, bool is_bcr_iti,byte ov, byte bl, byte sb,byte nt, byte iv, byte seq, byte cy, byte ca)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Ahmed Aek Ben Jemia\\Desktop\\newest\\command combo\\1\\iec104_master_slave_rtu\\Combo_1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string updateCommand = null,updateCommand1=null;
                connection.Open();
                ConnectionState state = connection.State;

                float f = 0;

                string prev_status = string.Format("SELECT STATUS FROM ") + type_id + string.Format("_Table WHERE ASDU={0} AND IOA={1}", station, ioa);
                    try
                    {
                    f = ExecuteQueryWithResult_fl(connection, prev_status);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        SetText2(e.ToString());
                    }                  
            }

        }
```

> Error : System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

PS  : I can get string & byte values from database , this only happens with float and int.

Comment: What happens? Does it just hang? Does an invalid value get returned? Does an exception happen? What *happens*? Also: is there any chance the SQL is simply doing something silly? What is `query`?

Comment: What about a try-catch block to detect the error message ?

Comment: Try putting it in a try catch to see the error. Is your connection open? Is your query syntax correct. It's helpful to show all relevant code to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and ensure your that your connection is open already.

```
static float ExecuteQueryWithResult_fl(SqlConnection connection, string query)   {
            try {        
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    var prev_val = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == null ? default(float) : float.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());;
                    return prev_val;
                }
            }

           catch (Exception x) 
           { 
                Console.WriteLine("Error fetching due to {0}", x.Message); 
                return default(float);
           }
     }
```

**Update:**
Replace your query with:

```
string prev_status = string.Format("SELECT cast(STATUS as float) prev_status FROM {0}_Table WHERE ASDU={1} AND IOA={2}",type_id, station, ioa);
```

Comment: the exception should *already* be being thrown, so that doesn't necessarily help much compared to just *looking at the existing exception*, even if it compiled (which it doesn't); it also assumes that the code is running in a console, which I suspect is highly unlikely

Comment: @MarcGravell ... or a Forms/WPF application, the output of which would then be visible in Visual Studio.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar well, possibly; but if you're going to be using Visual Studio, do you know what else is visible? *the original exception*, and *break-points*...

Comment: @MarcGravell I know and I'm with you on criticising this answer, but your assumption that this code must be running in a console is wrong. Of course he should debug properly.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I wrote the code on the browser but now editied to fix it. Based on the question he's saying client application and also it's just a hint for him to display the error in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks ... usable (although I'd be very concerned about how you are passing in parameters); your code works fine when called like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    float f;
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        f = ExecuteQueryWithResult_fl(conn, "select cast(1.23 as float(24))");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(f); // 1.23
}
```

So the problem *isn't the method you've shown* (by itself). To understand what is happening, you should use a debugger and see what happens. My guess would be one of:

- an invalid cast (the difference between `float` in C# and the SQL Server data types)
- invalid SQL from concatenating values into the query (a very very bad thing to do)

combined with calling code that is swallowing an `Exception` without displaying it to you. The debugger will tell you, once you have a break-point at the location that isn't working.